# How to add command line parameter dependency using JCommander?

Tags: java, command-line, jcommander, args4j

I am using JCommander for command line parameters parsing. I would like to add parameter dependency, but from the JCommander documentation, I am not able to find out if it is even supported. Has anyone tried it ?
For example, java -jar Some.jar -a Foo -b Hola
So, option -b shall only accompany with option -a.

This is [supported in args4j](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/args4j/apidocs/org/kohsuke/args4j/Option.html#depends()). However, I can't use args4j because it does not support [multiple values as JCommander](http://jcommander.org/apidocs/com/beust/jcommander/Parameter.html#names()).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use args4j, it does support multiple values.

JCommander:

```
@Parameter(names={"--length", "-l"})
int length;
```

Args4j:

```
@Option(name = "-l", aliases = { "--length" })
int length;
```

About validation and dependency: You can do this manually, of course. It's not too much of programming. Just ignore option b if a is not given either, or throw an exception if a is non-null but b is null.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem but it looks like that args4j has added support for multiple values:

```
import org.kohsuke.args4j.spi.StringArrayOptionHandler;

@Option(name = "-p", handler = StringArrayOptionHandler.class, required = true)
private List<String> list;
```

which should allow

```
-p arg1 arg2 ...
```